# How to pass JSON to FetchAPI Response

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I'm trying to create [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response) object and can't figure out how to pass json body in it.

Should I create a [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/ReadableStream)? If so, how can I do it?

I'm trying it offhand:

```
const stream = new ReadableStream({
  start(controller) {
    controller.enqueue(JSON.stringify({message: 'Test'}));
  },
});

new Response(stream, {
  status: 304,
  statusText: 'Not Modified',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
  },
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why do you want to create a `Response` by hand? `fetch` already returns one.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Hi @Andreas, thanks for the observation, do you have any answer for my question?

Comment: No, because I don't understand why you want to create such an object in the first place. I see no real reason why I would want to do this. Even if it would be for testing purposes (mocking) I think there would be better ways to do (such as to not expose the raw response directly)

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" means what? What goes wrong, exactly? An error? Some other unexpected behaviour? Please be clear and specific about the nature of the problem. Also what's the context for this code? It's unclear how what you have shown relates to fetch exactly. And as Andreas says, what is the purpose of this code? Then we can understand if this is even the best way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @ADyson, sorry, my bad, I did not think that this would require context. I need it return custom response from service worker's fetch event. "doesn't seem to work" basically means that no body appears in the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I was a little hasty to create a question here. It turned out to be a lot easier than I thought, no ReadableStream required:

```
new Response(JSON.stringify({message: 'Test'}), {
  status: 418,
  statusText: 'Teapot',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
  },
});
```

My mistake was that I tried to set a body to a Response with [null body status](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#null-body-status).